# Python: ERROR:Column "open" does not exist

Tags: python, flask

When I click the link to execute the query to bring in the tickets where the status is set to open I get column "open" does not exist. Yet "open" is a value and not a column. Here's my python code.

```
@app.route('/supportTicket')
def supportTicket():
    try:
        conn=None
        conn=getConn()
        cur= conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SET search_path to public')
        cur.execute('SELECT ticket.ticketid, problem, status, priority, loggedtime,updatetime, customerid, productid FROM ticket INNER JOIN ticketupdate ON ticket.ticketid = ticketupdate.ticketid  WHERE status =`open`')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if rows:
            return render_template('supportTicket.html', rows = rows)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', msg1='no data found')

    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('index.html', msg1='No data found', error1 = e)

    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: Backticks are for fieldnames.  Replace `open` with "open".

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: I don't think you're getting the same error with " instead of `.  Perhaps your changed code is not actually running somehow?

Comment: I already tried using double quotes earlier. I get this. column "open" does not exist LINE 1: ...icket.ticketid = ticketupdate.ticketid WHERE status ="open" ^

Answer (score 0):

You are using backticks for quoting **open**.  In Mysql backticks are used to quote identifiers not string literals. Backticks allow you to use keywords like "table", "select", etc as field names.  You must use single quotes around string literals.

So use double quotes around your python string and single quotes for **open**.

Comment: The problem still persists

Comment: I get this: column "open" does not exist LINE 1: ...icket.ticketid = ticketupdate.ticketid WHERE status ="open" ^

Comment: You must use **single** quotes to quote strings not double quotes. What database are you using?

Comment: That's why double quotes won't work. Mysql allows double quotes for strings but Postgresql does not.